# High delays with HTTPS only (!) in internal network

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, https, reverse-proxy, letsencrypt

I am really desperate. Since about 3 months I have a problem and could not find a solution yet. The problem first occured with a media server (direct access - no reverse proxy between) I am using.

The problem:

- HTTPS connections are very slow (1s-5s) when accessing webserver (Apache2 and the one integrated into the media server)
- Access is via DynDNS address (I do not use different urls when on the in- or external network)
- Fast HTTPS when accessing from the internet
- Fast connections via HTTP and SSH no matter the location (internal + external)
- Apache is the webserver (Nextcloud) + reverse proxy (Gitea and media server)
- The media server is reachable over the Reverse proxy and directly via IP + Port (Direct only HTTP since the reverse proxy). Setup the reverse proxy now because I tried to solve the problem using this (Remember: The problem first occured with the media server).
- Browser does not matter, the device does not matter (I tested with IE, Chrome, FF and Edge on two Windows devices and FF + Chrome on Android)
- So an example: I am at home (in internal network). I am opening two tabs on the same device in the same browser: One accessing via HTTP (blazing fast) and one over HTTPS (slow). When on the external network (access from outside) both HTTP and HTTPS are (almost) equally fast.

Software used:

- OS: Ubuntu Server 14.04
- Webserver: Apache2 2.4.7
- SSL: Lets Encrypt with Certbot => Auto-Mode enabled for Apache
- Client: Android and Windows 10

Symptoms:

- In internal network the upload seems to be limited to 100 KB/s on HTTPS. Download: No limited seeable. The problem kicks in when you access a webpage on the apache2 which loads images or scripts in the background which takes more time.
- DNS, TLS-Configuration and Blocked are the things taking up the time (not all three the same time) according to FF dev tools
- Every request takes between 1s and 5s (!)

I ran out of ideas. Regarding the system updates: 1-2 days before the issue an occured during the update of openssl. But unfortunalty everything still worked so I did not save the logs. That's why I assume openSSL or some other ssl libs are the problem. I really hope you guys can help me.

To come to some final questions:

- Did you ever experience such a weird error/misbehaviour or know what might be the problem and how it can be solved?
- Is everything okay with my ssl libraries/open ssl installation?
- What is the best way to "repair" a package (esp. OpenSSL)?

This is was previously asked [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/984855/high-delays-with-https-only-in-internal-network) by me. I did not know home questions are not allowed there. But what became clear from this is: If I access the server directly via e.g. `https://<localip>/nextcloud` the connection is fast. Ofc I have to ignore a lot of ssl warnings.

Here are the packages (in case you want to know) [with ssl in its name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJM1s.png). If you need more information please let me know. I can't update my Ubuntu installation as some required drivers would break. I will make a full backup/migration on a new server next year, because of money.